# runtime analysis (Time Complexity)

Tags: time, runtime, complexity-theory, analysis

```cpp
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(i == x) {
        for(j=0; j<x; j++) {
            x++;
        }
        x *= 2;
    }
}
```

What's the runtime analysis for this loop?

Comment: Any thoughts of your own?

Comment: What do you think? Explain it before going for help

Answer (score 0):

In the loop

```cpp
for(j=0; j<x; j++) {
    x++;
}
```

`j` will always be less than `x` if `x` starts out greater than zero. This is because you are incrementing `x` every time you increment `j`. In a language with arbitrary precision integer arithmetic, this will run until you run out of resources. In a language like C, this results in undefined behavior. The compiler could optimize `j<x` to always be true, or it could allow `x` to overflow to an undefined (but probably two's complement) result.